# how to check radio button is checked or not? i am getting Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"700700139"} error in console

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input id="700690188" class="default_shipping_address" 
type="radio" name="address" checked="true">
```

and i am trying with below code:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("700700139")).isSelected()){
System.out.println(driver.findElement(
   By.xpath("//input[@id='700700139']/following-sibling::span[1]")).getText());
```

Comment: Is it under any `frames` ? Please provide complete html of this radio button

Comment: What's the URL of the web-page that you are trying to access?

Answer (score 4):

You are using a different id than the one on the page. You say the page shows an element with id 700690188 but you are querying for 700700139

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version/type of control will depend on the usage of the .isSelected  If your `input` element is not working with the .isSelected for some reason...it should..., then you can check the attribute `@checked` for true or false.  Personally I would pare these together in a function and call it to return a true/false.  That way I can check any of them with the same code.

c#

```
     if (IsSelected(driver.findElement(By.id("700690188")))
          System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='700690188']/following-sibling::span[1]")).getText());

     public bool IsSelected(IWebElement element)
     {
         try
         {
             return element.isSelected();
         }
         catch
         {
             if(element.GetAttribute("checked") == "true")
                 return true;
             else
                 return false;
         }
     }
```

If neither of the above work then there is something funky with your input element.

Edit:
changed the ID in the example as Bryan is right, the webpage and your element id don't match.